# Modifying Python Code so it doesn't repeat

Tags: python

Here's the [link](https://repl.it/join/xoiphgzw-michellehan1) to my code.

**Original Question:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwwZa.png)

Right now, when I print my code, I get

> People in positions 2 through 4 , flip your caps!
>
> People in positions 6 through 8 , flip your caps!
>
> People in positions 11 through 11 , flip your caps!

But, I want to change it so that firstly, there isn't a space between the number and the comma, and also I want to make it so that the last command says "**Person at position 11, flip your cap!**"

Could someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Why have you added 2 functions that do the same task?

Comment: uhhh i think one is for forwards and the other is for backwards. I'm not sure though, since I'm very new to coding and python. :/

Comment: They are exactly the same, only the names are different

Comment: oh ok, i'll remove the second one then. can you help me with my question though?

Comment: Sure, doing! Can you post the question also, it'll be a great help :)

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: ok sure, thank you so much! :D

Comment: unable to access the code from the link you posted. can you post your code here so we can see it within SO please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the first: You can use print('f as shown below.
2. For the second, you need a if statement to check the elements,

```
if t[1] != t[2]:  **# 2.check the elements**
    print (f'People in positions {t[0]}, through {t[1]}, flip your caps!')
else:
    print(f'People in positions {t[1]}, flip your caps!')
```